# How do I create a column such that its values is count of the number of,1, in that row, which are appearing for the first time in their own column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, series

How do I do this operation using pandas?

Initial Df:

```
    A B C D
0   0 1 0 0
1   0 1 0 0
2   0 0 1 1
3   0 1 0 1
4   1 1 0 0
5   1 1 1 0
```

Final Df:

```
    A B C D Param
0   0 1 0 0     1
1   0 1 0 0     0
2   0 0 1 1     2
3   0 1 0 1     0
4   1 1 0 0     1
5   1 1 1 0     0
```

Basically Param is the number of the 1 in that row which is appearing for the first time in its own column.
Example:
index 0 : 1 in the column B is appearing for the first time hence Param1 = 1

index 1 : none of the 1 is appearing for the first time in its own column hence Param1 = 0

index 2 : 1 in the column C and D is appearing for the first time  in their columns hence Paramm1 = 2

index 3 : none of the 1 is appearing for the first time in its own column hence Param1 = 0

index 4 : 1 in the column A is appearing for the first time  in the column hence Paramm1 = 1

index 5 : none of the 1 is appearing for the first time in its own column hence Param1 = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do `idxmax` and `value_counts`

```
df['Param']=df.idxmax().value_counts().reindex(df.index,fill_value=0)
df
   A  B  C  D  Param
0  0  1  0  0      1
1  0  1  0  0      0
2  0  0  1  1      2
3  0  1  0  1      0
4  1  1  0  0      1
5  1  1  1  0      0
```

Comment: This will return wrong result if some column does not have `1` values, though this is unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for duplicated values, multiply with `df` and sum:

```
df['Param'] = df.apply(lambda x: ~x.duplicated()).mul(df).sum(1)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D  Param
0  0  1  0  0      1
1  0  1  0  0      0
2  0  0  1  1      2
3  0  1  0  1      0
4  1  1  0  0      1
5  1  1  1  0      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are integers, you can use cumsum() twice to isolate the first occurrence of 1.

```
df2 = (df.cumsum() > 0).cumsum() == 1
df['Param'] = df2.sum(axis = 1)
print(df)
```

If df elements are strings, you should first convert them to integers.

```
df = df.astype(int)
```